# How to use if / else statement in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am a beginner to jQuery, and I cannot figure out why my if/else statements are not working as expected. Can you help me?

```
.on('click', '#done-searchuber', function () {
    var $$ = $(this);

    if (!$('#fullname_input').val()) {
        $$.loginErrorScript('The full name is raquired!');
        return true;
    } else {
        if ($$.next('div').exists()) {
            $$.execValidationScript();
        }
        return false;
    }

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($('#age_input').val()))) {
        $$.loginErrorScript('Your age is incorrect!');
        return true;
    } else {
        if ($$.next('div').exists()) {
            $$.execValidationScript();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check your browser console?

Comment: If you could include the HTML as well, or put a MCVE up on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that would be helpful.

Comment: `Not work fine` is not really descriptive. You need to tell what the desired behaviour of your code is and what the wrong behaviour is.

Comment: We need more information on what especifically is going wrong

Comment: The problem is that you have  `return` in both the `if` and the `else` block. So the second if will never be evaluated. But without telling the expected behaviour it is not possible to tell how the code should be changed.

Comment: please people don't tell me what i write, if you can help us, help us, if you can't don't tell us any thing common gays! grow up!

Comment: @t.niese thanks for your answer, can you correct that and give me the code i try to remove return but not working thank you

Comment: @iklas as I already said it is not possible to correct the code, because you don't tell what the code is expected to do and what is the wrong behaviour. It would be easy solve the problem if you would provide more details. But the only thing you do is to ignore those comments and telling the people that are willed to help you that the should grow up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a simple way you could tidy up what you already have; because you have multiple points of return you negate the need to have several else clauses you don't need.

It also has the added benefit of making you're code a bit easier to read.

```
.on('click', '#done-searchuber', function () {
                var $$ = $(this);

                if (!$('#fullname_input').val()) {
                    $$.loginErrorScript('The full name is raquired!');
                    return true;
                }

                if ($$.next('div').exists()) {
                    $$.execValidationScript();
                    return false;
                }

                if (isNaN(parseFloat($('#age_input').val()))) {
                    $$.loginErrorScript('Your age is incorrect!');
                    return true;
                } 

                if ($$.next('div').exists()) {
                    $$.execValidationScript();
                    return false;
                }
})
```

Comment: you are awesome this solution is working perfecty
and i have second solution is working two 
`var  $$ = $(this);
if(!$('#fullname_input').val() ) {
    $$.agenameErrorScript('Full name is required');
    return; }else{
        $$.execValidationScript();
               }
                    if (isNaN(parseFloat($('#age_input').val()))) {
                        $$.agenameErrorScript('Your age is incorrect!');
                        return ;
                    }
                    else{
                        $$.execValidationScript();
                    }`
Thank you so so much

Answer (score 0):

thank you @Stevie for i test your code and is working fine with me 
i have also another solution is working:

```
.on('click', '#done-searchuber', function () {
                    var
                            $$ = $(this);

                    if(!$('#fullname_input').val() ) {
                        $$.agenameErrorScript('Full name is required');
                        return;
                    }
                    else{
                        $$.execValidationScript();
                    }
                    if (isNaN(parseFloat($('#age_input').val()))) {
                        $$.agenameErrorScript('Your age is incorrect!');
                        return ;
                    }
                    else{
                        $$.execValidationScript();
                    }
```

thank you stevie